# TKChartDataPoint does not conform to expected type Sequence

Tags: ios, swift, telerik

I am starting out with **Telerik** and tried to do the demo project provided.

As I am trying to declare a **TKChartDataPoint** it gives out an error:
[image: Error Image]

Code Snippet:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let x = 10
let y = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let chart = TKChart(frame: self.view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 15, dy: 15))
    chart.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    self.view.addSubview(chart)

    var randomNumericData = [TKChartDataPoint]()
    for i in 0..<10 {

        //Error Here
        randomNumericData += TKChartDataPoint(x: i, y: Double(arc4random() % 100))

    }

    chart.addSeries(TKChartLineSeries(items: randomNumericData))

    chart.title.isHidden = false
    chart.title.text = "This is a chart demo"
    chart.legend.isHidden = false

    chart.allowAnimations = true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use `append` to add your object to the array:

```
randomNumericData.append(TKChartDataPoint(x: i, y: Double(arc4random() % 100)))
```

You can use `+=` if you really want, but `randomNumericData` is an Array so to add to it with `+` or `+=`, the added part should also be an array:

```
randomNumericData += [TKChartDataPoint(x: i, y: Double(arc4random() % 100))]
```

In my opinion, the first solution is preferred.